# When slicing one row of dataframe, drop NaN columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is, how can I drop NaN columns when slicing one row off a dataframe?

I am slicing a dataframe one row at a time. Say for example the dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
```

I'm going to change one value to NaN for demonstration:

```
df.iloc[2,3] = np.NaN
```

Resulting df is:

```
    A   B      C    D
0   foo one    0    0.0
1   bar one    1    2.0
2   foo two    2    NaN
3   bar three  3    6.0
4   foo two    4    8.0
5   bar two    5    10.0
6   foo one    6    12.0
7   foo three  7    14.0
```

I will be returning one row at a time as part of a larger operation. This is an example:

```
df.iloc[2,:]
```

When I do this I get:

```
A    foo
B    two
C      2
D    NaN
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

I'm going to need to iterate over this row, which may only contain one of many columns. Is there a vector or pythonic way to not return the columns with NaN? I'm trying to avoid iterating over the whole row or using a dictionary, which will also need iteration.

Ideally, the result should look like this:

```
A    foo
B    two
C      2
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: you mean `df.iloc[2,:].dropna()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 you beat me to it! always on the pandas lookout huh?

Comment: @anky_91 I was about to tell you how that didn't work when I tried it, and then it worked. I must have typo-ed something.  Thanks  question answered.

Comment: Urrrgggg.... sometimes.

Comment: @DiegoAguado just checked casually. :P

Comment: @run-out happens. :) glad you found your solution. :)